# Гарантированный запуск Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Есть относительно критический Windows Service, который должне гарантированно запускаться в случае перезагрузки системы.

Проблема в том, что система после перезагрузки (точнее, пересоздания VM) достаточно сильно тормозит, и старт сервиса падает с ошибкой:

> The ServiceName service failed to start due to the following error: 
>   The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Cудя по логам, код в OnStart у сервиса не вызывается, так что запросить дополнительное время вызовом `ServiceBase.RequestAdditionalTime` не получается.

Сервис падает, даже если OnStart пустой. Судя по всему, инициализация CLR просто не вписывается в стандартный таймаут.

При этом сервис нормально и быстро стартует на уже загрузившейся системе.

Настройки Recovery в свойствах сервиса не помогают - они применяются только в случае, если сервис упал уже после успешного запуска.

Есть ли простой/стандартный/удобный способ гарантировать старт windows service в условиях тормозов системы при старте?

Comment: Пробовали `Automatic Delayed` Startup type?

Comment: @AntonKomyshan пробовал, не помогает

Comment: @AntonKomyshan я успел найти варианты с [generatePublisherEvidence](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1437.ad-fs-2-0-the-service-fails-to-start-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion.aspx) (не уверен применимо ли, и не дает гарантии) и с [watchdog в виде scheduled task](https://octopus.com/docs/administration/service-watchdog) (сервис octopus точно так же падает на той же машине, решение пока не пробовал). ищу альтернативные решения

Comment: А если сначала запустить пустой сервис на .NET, а когда тот запустится/не запустится, запускать свой? Своего рода «прогрев».

Comment: @VladD это примерно то же самое,  что Automatic (Delayed). Не помогает. Т.е. на машине несколько managed сервисов. Из них некоторые стартуют даже без Delayed, некоторые падают даже с Delayed. Причем результат непредсказуем - такое ощущение, что падает просто в случае "не повезло". Т.е. меня бы вполне устроил retry в случае, если первый старт упал (т.е. разогрев самим собой)  - но каким-то более-менее надежным способом. Ищу вот этот способ :)

Comment: Нельзя сделать сервис зависимым от системного, чтобы самому запускаться просто попозже? К какому-нибудь логически связанному с вашим - сетевой там, журнал событий виндовый, что лучше будет. Костыль конечно, но мало ли. Прод не раз видел попинываемый шедулером, всё лучше чем ничего.

Comment: Еще можно попробовать в настройках сервиса выставить повторный запуск после первого и второго сбоя, но не уверен, что это сработает, если сервис не смог запуститься в первый раз. Ну и побочный эффект есть - повторный запуск будет срабатывать и на "штатное" падение сервиса, например при кривых входных данных или еще какой ошибке, когда он просто должен упасть.

Comment: @rdorn выставлено, срабатывает на штатное падение, но не срабатывает при таймауте на старте

Comment: @Monk просто попозже не помогает (становится лучше, но все равно изредка падает) :( судя по всему, придется пинать шедулером. постараюсь найти готовое решение для пинков, не хочется велосипед писать

Comment: Пробовали увеличивать время отложеного старта?

Comment: Если служба установлена и зарегистрирована как положено - `net start <serviceName>` в шедулер с триггером на запуск системы. А там уже можно откладывать хоть на секунду, хоть на сутки, с повторением попыток и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решили проблему добавлением задачи в Task Scheduler, которая периодически проверяет состояние сервиса и стартует его, если он еще не запущен.

Наверное, можно было бы обойтись `net start servicename`, но прикрутили чуть более длинный скрипт:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ServiceName=%~1

SC QUERYEX "%ServiceName%" | FIND "STATE" | FIND /v "RUNNING" > NUL && (
    ECHO %ServiceName% is not running 
    ECHO START %ServiceName%

    NET START "%ServiceName%" > NUL || (
        ECHO "%ServiceName%" wont start 
        EXIT /B 1
    )
    ECHO "%ServiceName%" is started
    EXIT /B 0
) || (
    ECHO "%ServiceName%" is running
    EXIT /B 0
)
```

[Скрипт для создания таска через Octopus](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-templates/17bc51d1-8b88-4aad-b188-24a0904d0bf2/actiontemplate-windows-scheduled-task-create):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest";

# use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx for API reference

Function Create-ScheduledTask($TaskName,$RunAsUser,$RunAsPassword,$TaskRun,$Arguments,$Schedule,$StartTime,$StartDate,$RunWithElevatedPermissions,$Days,$Interval,$Duration)
{

    # SCHTASKS /Create [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
    #     [/RU username [/RP password]] /SC schedule [/MO modifier] [/D day]
    #     [/M months] [/I idletime] /TN taskname /TR taskrun [/ST starttime]
    #     [/RI interval] [ {/ET endtime | /DU duration} [/K] [/XML xmlfile] [/V1]]
    #     [/SD startdate] [/ED enddate] [/IT | /NP] [/Z] [/F] [/HRESULT] [/?]

    # note - /RL and /DELAY appear in the "Parameter list" for "SCHTASKS /Create /?" but not in the syntax above

    $argumentList = @();
    $argumentList += @( "/Create" );

    $argumentList += @( "/RU", $RunAsUser );

    if( -not (StringIsNullOrWhiteSpace($RunAsPassword)))
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/RP", $RunAsPassword );
    }

    $argumentList += @( "/SC", $Schedule );

    if( -not (StringIsNullOrWhiteSpace($Interval)) )
    {
        switch -Regex ($Schedule)
        {
            "MINUTE|HOURLY|ONLOGON|ONIDLE" {
                $argumentList += @( "/MO", $Interval );
            }
            "WEEKLY|MONTHLY" {
                $argumentList += @( "/RI", $Interval );
            }
            "ONCE|ONSTART|ONEVENT" {
                # we don't currently support providing an XPATH query string
                throw new-object System.NotImplementedException("Unsupported schedule option '$Schedule'.");
            }
        }
    }

    if( -not (StringIsNullOrWhiteSpace($Days)) -And $Schedule -Ne "DAILY" )
    {
        if($Schedule -ne "WEEKDAYS") {
            $argumentList += @( "/D", $Days );
        } else {
            $argumentList += @( "/D", "MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI" );
        }
    }

    $argumentList += @( "/TN", "`"$TaskName`"" );

    if( $Arguments )
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/TR", "`"'$TaskRun' $Arguments`"" );
    }
    else
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/TR", "`"'$TaskRun'`"" );
    }

    if( -not (StringIsNullOrWhiteSpace($StartTime)) )
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/ST", $StartTime );
    }

    if( -not (StringIsNullOrWhiteSpace($Duration)) )
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/DU", $Duration );
    }

    if( -not (StringIsNullOrWhiteSpace($StartDate)) )
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/SD", $StartDate );
    }

    $argumentList += @( "/F" );

    if( $RunWithElevatedPermissions )
    {
        $argumentList += @( "/RL", "HIGHEST" );
    }

    Invoke-CommandLine -FilePath     "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\schtasks.exe" `
                       -ArgumentList $argumentList;

}

Function Delete-ScheduledTask($TaskName) {
    # SCHTASKS /Delete [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
    #          /TN taskname [/F] [/HRESULT] [/?]
    Invoke-CommandLine -FilePath     "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\schtasks.exe" `
                       -ArgumentList @( "/Delete", "/S", "localhost", "/TN", "`"$TaskName`"", "/F" );
}

Function Stop-ScheduledTask($TaskName) {
    # SCHTASKS /End [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]]
    #          /TN taskname [/HRESULT] [/?]
    Invoke-CommandLine -FilePath     "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\schtasks.exe" `
                       -ArgumentList @( "/End", "/S", "localhost", "/TN", "`"$TaskName`"" );
}

Function Start-ScheduledTask($TaskName) {
    # SCHTASKS /Run [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] [/I]
    #          /TN taskname [/HRESULT] [/?]
    Invoke-CommandLine -FilePath     "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\schtasks.exe" `
                       -ArgumentList @( "/Run", "/S", "localhost", "/TN", "`"$TaskName`"" );
}

Function Enable-ScheduledTask($TaskName) {
    # SCHTASKS /Change [/S system [/U username [/P [password]]]] /TN taskname
    #      { [/RU runasuser] [/RP runaspassword] [/TR taskrun] [/ST starttime]
    #        [/RI interval] [ {/ET endtime | /DU duration} [/K] ]
    #        [/SD startdate] [/ED enddate] [/ENABLE | /DISABLE] [/IT] [/Z] }
    #        [/HRESULT] [/?]
    Invoke-CommandLine -FilePath     "$($env:SystemRoot)\System32\schtasks.exe" `
                       -ArgumentList @( "/Change", "/S", "localhost", "/TN", "`"$TaskName`"", "/ENABLE" );
}

Function ScheduledTask-Exists($taskName) {
   $schedule = new-object -com Schedule.Service
   $schedule.connect()
   $tasks = $schedule.getfolder("\").gettasks(0)
   foreach ($task in ($tasks | select Name)) {
      #echo "TASK: $($task.name)"
      if($task.Name -eq $taskName) {
         #write-output "$task already exists"
         return $true
      }
   }
   return $false
}

Function StringIsNullOrWhitespace([string] $string)
{
    if ($string -ne $null) { $string = $string.Trim() }
    return [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($string)
}

function Invoke-CommandLine
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $FilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string[]] $ArgumentList = @( ),
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string[]] $SuccessCodes = @( 0 )
    )
    write-host ($FilePath + " " + ($ArgumentList -join " "));
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath $FilePath -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru;
    if( $SuccessCodes -notcontains $process.ExitCode )
    {
        throw new-object System.InvalidOperationException("process terminated with exit code '$($process.ExitCode)'.");
    }
}

function Invoke-OctopusStep
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [hashtable] $OctopusParameters
    )

    $taskName = $OctopusParameters['TaskName']
    $runAsUser = $OctopusParameters['RunAsUser']
    $runAsPassword = $OctopusParameters['RunAsPassword']
    $command = $OctopusParameters['Command']
    $arguments = $OctopusParameters['Arguments']
    $schedule = $OctopusParameters['Schedule']
    $startTime = $OctopusParameters['StartTime']
    $startDate = $OctopusParameters['StartDate']

    if( $OctopusParameters.ContainsKey("RunWithElevatedPermissions") )
    {
        $runWithElevatedPermissions = [boolean]::Parse($OctopusParameters['RunWithElevatedPermissions'])
    }
    else
    {
        $runWithElevatedPermissions = $false;
    }

    $days = $OctopusParameters['Days']
    $interval = $OctopusParameters['Interval']
    $duration = $OctopusParameters['Duration']

    if((ScheduledTask-Exists($taskName))){
        Write-Output "$taskName already exists, Tearing down..."
        Write-Output "Stopping $taskName..."
        Stop-ScheduledTask($taskName)
        Write-Output "Successfully Stopped $taskName"
        Write-Output "Deleting $taskName..."
        Delete-ScheduledTask($taskName)
        Write-Output "Successfully Deleted $taskName"
    }
    Write-Output "Creating Scheduled Task - $taskName"

    Create-ScheduledTask $taskName $runAsUser $runAsPassword $command $arguments $schedule $startTime $startDate $runWithElevatedPermissions $days $interval $duration
    Write-Output "Successfully Created $taskName"
    Enable-ScheduledTask($taskName)
    Write-Output "$taskName enabled"

}


# only execute the step if it's called from octopus deploy,
# and skip it if we're runnning inside a Pester test
if( Test-Path -Path "Variable:OctopusParameters" )
{
    $ParamsForRunning = @{
      TaskName = 'Service WatchDog'
      RunAsUser= 'System'
      Command = $OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[Deploy Worker].Output.Package.InstallationDirectoryPath"]+"\check-service.cmd"
      Arguments = 'SomeWorkerServiceName'
      Schedule = 'MINUTE'
      Interval = 20
    }
    Invoke-OctopusStep -OctopusParameters $ParamsForRunning;
}
```

Не через Octopus - специфические вещи можно заменить на прямой вызов.

Из неудобств - при умышленной остановке сервиса приходится менять ему Startup Type на Disabled, чтобы избежать автозапуска.